# FreeTDS unixODBC concurrent connections

Tags: sql-server, go, freetds, unixodbc

I'm using Golang with FreeTDS using the ODBC driver from brainman (http://code.google.com/p/odbc)

Everything works great, until I stress test the box.

Then I get the following error:

> {01000} [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to open socket
>   SQLDriverConnect: {08001} [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to
>   connect to data source

It seems that when I try to launch multiple concurrent requests against the FreeTDS / unixODBC drivers, it fails. Is this something that is workable, or is unixODBC and FreeTDS not useable in production environments?

Comment: Are you seeing anything on the SQL server logs? From http://freetds.schemamania.org/faq.html#Are.there.any.known.issues "Errors can sometimes be confusing. When an application uses the library incorrectly, or when there are problems in a data file being uploaded with BCP, the message returned by FreeTDS can sometimes be misleading. In the latter case, it's often necessary to examine the log file to understand what went wrong."

Comment: To me, this looks like the failure of the FreeTDS driver to create a TCP/IP socket. Let's suppose the `odbc` package holds on TCP sockets contained in the connection objects it creates until those get garbage collected. Could you verify this? 1) Increase the limit on the number of opened files for the user whose account is used to run the stress test; 2) Use `netstat` or `ss` to verify how many outstanding TCP connection your application has. And finally consider bringing it on [the Go mailing list](http://groups.google.com/d/forum/golang-nuts) and *show the source code.*

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to an issue that I ran into. FreeTDS/ODBC on CentOS7 connecting to an SQLServer2005 database. I ended up creating 6 separate FreeTDS/ODBC DNS entries to have 6 discreet database connections available to use in order to resolve this issue (they were all just numbered duplicates of each other--$db, $db2, $db3, etc). It's not a great solution, but it does work (I was migrating a really old system, so my options were limited). I'd be very interested if there is a better solution than mine.